# Upgrade kubernetes from 1.5.5 to 1.5.8 or to 1.7/1.8

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I have deployed our kubernetes cluster in AWS using the kube-up scripts and ec2 instances. Can someone help me in figuring out how to upgrade this cluster to 1.5.8 or to the latest kubernetes release.

Comment: Watch out, IIRC the 1.5 to 1.6 boundary is when they mandated an etcd version change, unless you already happen to have etcd3 nodes. They also switched the default away from `application/json` for intra-cluster API traffic; there's a flag you can provide to switch it back, just watch out

Answer (score 1):

The way I gained confidence about the kind of upgrade you are describing is by setting up a Vagrant cluster of 1.5 api and nodes against the etcd:2 servers that were used at the time of 1.5, and then practice upgrading them to understand the moving parts and ways it can go foul.

Your use of `kube-up` is about the most manual(?) mechanism I know of, so you're starting from a mild disadvantage and thus need all the practice you can get.